# What is this Agda error?

Tags: agda

I'm trying out Agda for the first time and I've defined the `Bool` data type and its basic functions like all the tutorials say:

```
data Bool : Set where
true : Bool
false : Bool 
not : Bool -> Bool
not true = false
not false = true
etc...
```

When I try to load this it gets upset because "more than one matching type signature for left hand side not true" and it highlights "not true" in red. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to indent the data constructors of `Bool`.